# Angular - Text-Align position from ngmodel not taking effect when modal popup is closed

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have this div from an HTML component file

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'text-align':Setting.Position}" style="overflow:hidden">
```

The Setting.Position is a property that is in a component.ts file and it is being set from a modal with a dropdown (values either left, right, center) bound to Setting.Position model that is being loaded when a button is clicked.

After the button from the modal is clicked to save the value, the modal exits. However, the value of text-align is not reflected instantly. To have it take effect, I will need to reload the modal and exit.

I have already tried `window.location.reload()` but it reloads the whole page.

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: is the modal a separate component? How is the position value being sent from the modal component back to the main page? it'd be easier to help if there was some stackblitz example....

Comment: the modal component is a separate component. The position value is a global property that is available across all components and its value is bound in the select dropdown as an ng-model. In AngularJS, any updates to this ng-model reflects instantly across

Comment: Have you tried with ngClass instead of ngStyles??

Comment: ngClass not working

Comment: Ok, I got it to work. Since my components are using ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, I needed to add this.cd.markForCheck() in the method that is called after clicking the button in the dropdown since the modal and main page are different components;